# Deep Links or Universal Links for IOS APP

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

We've been following the manuals below:

https://blog.branch.io/es/como-configurar-universal-links-para-deep-linking-en-apple-ios/

https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

https://blog.branch.io/what-is-an-aasa-apple-app-site-association-file/

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW2

The file apple-app-site-association has been generated.
The associated Domains have been activated both in Xcode and in the task identifier.

File in the domain /apple-app-site-association { "applinks": { "apps": [], "details": [ { "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "paths": ["*"] } ] } } Active domains in the ios developer project and console

We have launched the checks and validations in the following URLS:
https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ --> Link to Application
Action required
Could not extract required information for Universal Links. Learn how to implement the recommended Universal Links.
Error no apps with domain entitlements
The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.

https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/ --> Krack wasn't able to be loaded
 Must be able to extract application (should be of IPA format)
 Must be able to find entitlements (looking in Krack/Payload/Krack.app/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent)
 Must have domains listed in com.apple.developer.associated-domains

https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox --> Result OK

We do not understand the steps or operations we still need to perform to make the deep links work in our IOS APP, in Android everything has been correct.

What we need is that when accessing from any link on iOS devices that have the app installed or not, the first thing you do is open the applestore to download it if you do not have it or open the app if you have it installed. And not that the browser is opened as it currently does by default

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Then [edit] your question, with a code example. Btw read [ask] and may take the [tour].

Comment: Edited the initial comment adding the report of information and data on the error that is reporting to us. If you need more information, please specify which one and we will look for it and provide it to you.

Comment: did you fix it?